Pagy Import styles confusion
I'm in the process of switching to the Pagy gem for pagination in my app.  I'm struggling to understand how to get the styles working.
I've looked at the docs here: https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/docs/api/stylesheets/, but it isn't clear if the styles are included in the gem, how can I use @import in my SCSS files to import them?
Can someone give me some help?

Yes, the style is included.
However, the included SCSS is static; to use it, you can simply copy and modify it.
The file is located at:
<pagy-gem-root>/stylesheets/pagy.scss
Caveat: I confirm the path with my local Pagy, which is version 8; I do not guarantee it won't change.
Alternatively, the gem provides element variants that are compatible with CSS frameworks, e.g., Bootstrap.
If you have Bootstrap already and use the Bootstrap variant, it will work out of the box.
No further styling setup needed and customization is optional.

So it's just expected that you copy the file and store it wherever you like in your sass setup?
I expected that you imported it from it's current location.  I assume that's not the case.

@rctneil It is there but unusable. The colors are hard-coded; like this: color: rgb(107 114 128);. You could try to import it where it is if you are okay with a grey, but that won't work for most people.
